# How to add multiple products to shopping cart magento programmatically

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento, shopping-cart

I want to add multiple products simultaneously to the magento shopping cart with custom calculated price!

How could I please help me guys

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi I am already tried the code from above link it works perfectly but I can't able to send my custom calculated price on the cart
http://www.lindenlan.net/2009/09/27/how-to-simultaneously-add-multiple-products-to-a-magento-shopping-cart/
please check and let me know if you have any solution in above!

Answer (score 0):

```
$cart = $this->_getCart();
$products = (prod_id_1,prod_id_2,prod_id_3);
$cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
$cart->save();
```

This will instantiate your cart and all multiple products to the cart at the same time.